# Variadic args. How to pass variadic args to a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a method that accept variadic arguments like

```
- (NSDictionary *) getImagePixelsAtLocation: (int) locations,...NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
```

but when I send message to this class method, the value of locations variable in called method is 0 (it does not matter how many arguments I pass).

The method receives scalar data types. My question is: Can we pass scalar variable to a method as variadic arguments? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

The method definition is:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getImagePixelsAtLocation: (int) pixel1,...
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pixel1);

    //processing logic


    va_end(args);
}
```

This is how I am sending message:

```
[HSImageProcessing getImagePixelsAtLocation:1,2,nil];
```

Comment: Can u Please add your method declaration or full method code.

Comment: I just tested, it works perfectly fine for me. Incidentally, passing nil to something expecting an int doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you're worried about it, just change the arg type to accept NSIntegers.

Comment: well. something funky going on. When I pass a pointer type variable (object) it gets received.

Comment: How can you have nil termination with a integer? It isn't possible, sorry.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I am sure nil termination is possible with integer also. Regarding the issue, I am not sure what was the problem, I restarted xcode, cleaned the project, and changed the compiler to LLVM 3.1 and then it starts working, wierd though, still can't figure out why it wasn't working earlier.

Comment: Thanks everyone for valuable contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is one glaringly obvious flaw in your code there: when a variadic function is nil-terminated, the accepted type must be an object.  You cannot compare an int to nil or NULL, or [NSNull null], which defeats the purpose of nil-termination, and effectively defeats all chances of iteration using the standard for and for-in loops.  In addition, NSDictionary isn't too happy about storing non-object types, and will happily make the compiler complain.  I've rewritten it to accept NSNumber*, and output a dictionary of numbers.

```
- (NSDictionary*) getImagePixelsAtLocation: (NSNumber*) pixel1,...
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pixel1);

    //processing logic
    for (NSNumber* arg = pixel1; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSNumber*)) {
        [dict setObject:arg forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [arg intValue]]];
    }

    va_end(args);
    return dict;
}
```

All it takes is a little bit of extra code on your part to get that very same call working as well:

```
[self getImagePixelsAtLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];
```

Comment: And that ugly code will get cleaner [in the future](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html): `[self getImagePixelsAtLocation:@1,@2,nil]`. Alternately, [you *could* do this with `int`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h), but then you'd need to terminate with zero (or `INT_MAX`, or some other sentinel value of your choosing).

Comment: Terminating with zero is dangerous as ints may be passed in that are in fact zero. In addition, zero is ***not nil***, nil is for id types.  Also, you're totally right about the literals, but I want to hold on to that ObjC 2.0 smell as long as possible before I jump into 2.1 ;P (that, and he might not have access to Xcode 4.5...)